# css drop-down issue

Tags: css

there! I am stuck with a simple css drop-down. You can see the code in the link below. My problem is that that when I put some link before the username it cannot be used because of the hover on the drop-down. I need the drop-down to be triggered only when hover over the user name but not the entire #userdrop div. Note that the z-index attribute is not my solution.

http://k-prim.biz/ttpm/demo.html

Comment: have you considered javascript?

Comment: any suggestions for javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the absolute positioning on #user. Lose that, and switch to float:right, with some margining (or something), and this should resolve itself.

Change this:

```
#user{
    position:absolute;right:30px; top:5px;  
    text-align:right;
    width: 202px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To this:

```
#user{
    float:right;right:30px; top:5px;  
    text-align:right;
    width: 202px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I just changed `position:absolute` to `float:right`, and it worked perfectly, aside from needing minor adjustments to the margin.

Comment: Or, just adjust the specified width, to be narrow enough not to cover it.

Comment: changing positioning does not help and the width cannot be fixed since the user name will be variable

Comment: Sure it does, I just double-checked, and clarified my answer.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, the width is currently fixed to 202px...

Answer (score 0):

Replace css and anchor tag according to this code

```
#link {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 124px;
    top: 5px;
}





#user {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    top: 5px;
    width: 202px;
    z-index: -1;
}



<a href="#" style="display: block; height: 28px; text-align: right; width: 76px;">Link here</a>
```

there is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7jexs/2/

Comment: yes it works but using z-index ;(

Comment: so y you are not using z-index